# What is ~/Library/VoiceTrigger/SAT ? Part of Siri?

Tags: siri, sip

What is this thing that we're not even allowed to look at?

```
sudo ls -late@ ~/Library/VoiceTrigger
Password:
ls: SAT: Operation not permitted
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  88 WGroleau  staff  2816 Feb 18 15:34 ..
drwxrwxr-x   3 WGroleau  staff    96 Mar 23  2019 .
WGroleau@MBP ~ %
```

https://appleinsider.com/articles/17/11/19/hey-siri-may-come-to-imac-pro-with-rumored-inclusion-of-a10-fusion-co-processor suggests it is for Siri.  The name suggests that, but I've always disabled Siri on MacOS (since it **always** misunderstands me on iPhone).  I understand the need for SIP, but preventing us from listing file names accomplishes absolutely nothing.

Of course, I can disable SIP and look, but that procedure is not fun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SAT stands for Siri Audio Transcripts.

It's a `UF_DATAVAULT`, a new type of privacy container in Catalina that restricts who can access the contents by specific entitlement. This means nothing can access the contents except the individual binary granted the individual entitlement.

Comment: So Siri must have been on at some time, against my wishes.

Comment: In theory, how would you get around this? Would turning off SIP and AMFI be sufficient, or would you need to actually compile a binary and grant it the restricted entitlements (which you can do, because there's no AMFI)?